# Absolute Path Selenium Chromedriver Ubuntu (Python)

Tags: python, selenium, ubuntu-16.04

I am trying to run a script (Python3.5), but get the error 'chromedriver' executable needs to be in PATH.  I know I can change the PATH variable, but I wanted to use an absolute path.  I went to the documentation https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/getting-started

The code example they used:

```
import time
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Chrome('/path/to/chromedriver') #Optional argument, if     not specified will search path.
```

My code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3.5
from pyvirtualdisplay import Display
from selenium import webdriver

display = Display(visible=0, size=(800, 600))
display.start()
driver=webdriver.Chrome(
"/home/ubuntu/Downloads/chromedriver")
driver.get('https://python.org')
print (driver.title)
```

Any suggestions for why the absolute path is not working?

Solved the issue.  I needed to added: executable_path, so driver = webdriver.Chrome(**executable_path**="home/ubuntu/Downloads/chromedriver") and now it runs fine.

Comment: absolute path works fine for me.  what error are you getting?

Comment: @Corey Goldberg: This is the traceback error I get: File "/home/ubuntu/virtenv/scrapeit/lib/python3.5/site-packages/selenium/webdr                                                                             iver/common/service.py", line 81, in start
    os.path.basename(self.path), self.start_error_message)
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: 'chromdriver' executable                                                                              needs to be in PATH.

Comment: execute on terminal: `sudo chmod +x home/ubuntu/Downloads/chromedriver`, also check the name `chromdriver`