# selenium can not use chromedriver

Tags: selenium-chromedriver

I am trying to get selenium to use chromedriver on mac.

I have downloaded the mac version of chromedriver and added it to application folder.

when I use driver = webdriver.Chrome("/Applications/chromedriver"),it can work with using relative path, while, when I use driver=  webdriver.Chrome("/Users/Angel/Applications/chromedriver"),it can not work with using absolute path.

Could you please tell me why? Thank you very much.

Comment: Did you look here:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43099425/absolute-path-selenium-chromedriver-ubuntu-python

Comment: Yes,I have tried that with adding executable_path, but it does not work.